# Count neighbors at radius $r_m$

Tags: computational-geometry, point-cloud, neighbourhood

I have a point cloud of $50,000$ points in a 3D space.

I want to **count** the number of neighbors **each** point $\{(x_1,y_1,z_1), (x_2,y_2,z_2), (x_3,y_3,z_3), ... ...,(x_N,y_N,z_N)\}$ has at radii $\{r_1, r_2, r_3, ..., r_M\}$.

Which algorithm should I use?

Comment: Maybe a good question for the [Computational Science stack](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using a [k-D tree algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree). Often used in raytracers as well but slightly less efficient you may also want to partition some domain of your coordinate system into a [quadtree](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) if your points are evenly distributed or an [R-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) if you can always decide a statistical distribution for their concentration.